# How to round regression coefficients using getSummary from memisc library?

Tags: r, rounding

I'm doing some basic regression analysis using `getSummary` from `memisc` library. The script looks like this:

```
lm0 <- lm(formula = X~Y, data=dataframe)
lm1 <- lm(formula = X~Y+Z, data=dataframe)

getSummary(lm0, alpha=.05)
getSummary(lm1, alpha=.05)
```

And the output looks like this:

```
$sumstat
        sigma     r.squared adj.r.squared             F 
 1.312559e+00  4.612393e-02  4.520586e-02  5.024003e+01 
        numdf         dendf             p        logLik 
 1.000000e+00  1.039000e+03  2.508404e-12 -1.759244e+03 
     deviance           AIC           BIC             N 
 1.790001e+03  3.524488e+03  3.539332e+03  1.041000e+03
```

What I don't know is how to round the regession coefficients to look like this:

```
    $sumstat
 r.squared     adj.r.squared             
 4.6           4.5
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `getSummary` is just a `list`, so

```
s = getSummary(lm1, alpha=.05)
## Extract values
values = s$sumstat[c("r.squared", "adj.r.squared")]
## Round 
round(values, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution but it's doing something slightly different. The output now looks like this:  `r.squared 0.05`. But i want something that looks like this `r.squared 4.5`

Comment: R.squared is a value between 0 and 1. If you want a value between 0 and 100, then multiply it by 100 - `values*100`

Comment: I have one related question. How can I create a function that will apply the rounding of regression coefficients to other models? I mean to lm1, lm2, lmx.